# Create new column based on specific cell value

Tags: powerquery

I need to create a new column containing repeatedly a specific cell value.
In Column1, Row1 the table contains the exam name. Lets say "Exam1". I now need a new column with this text value "Exam1" for all of my students. The new columns name would then be "Exam-Name" and all the rows should have as content the exam name "Exam1".
How can I reference to a specific content in a specific cell and have this text as value for all of my rows in a new column?
[image]

Concrete: I need the value "MMA20aL..." to be the value in the row on the right where actually you find the contents "KE21a..."

Thank you for your help. I pretty new to PowerQuery, thank you for a detailed explanation :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? _"thank you for a detailed explanation :-)"_ There are so many tutorials out there - did your work through them and have specific questions? Then you are ready for SO - otherwise please try to get some basic knowledge and then come back and show us where you have problems. Reading [ask] might help your for further details.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the first cell and drill down it will show you a formula. Make note of that formula then remove the drill down step.

Add column ... custom column ... with column name Exam-Name and the formula it showed you, such as :

```
= Source{0}[Column1]
```

Where Source in above formula is the name of prior step and Column1 is the name of the first column

So, for example, if prior step is #"Changed Type" and the first column is named Bob then use instead

```
= #"Changed Type"{0}[Bob]
```

(As a note, your data is in a terrible format and needs much massaging before it would be really useful)

Comment: Shure it is in a terrible format. The image above is an image of one of the first steps. There are a lot of following steps which then work through the entries and clean up the whole table :-)

Comment: Well, if it worked perfectly, great. Please accept the answer then using the checkmark toggle by the arrows